# Ключ воды и ключ дверной

Tags: словообразование

Почему в первом случае "к" будет приставкой,а во втором - "-юч" будет суффиксом?

**Ключ воды и ключ дверной**

Answer (score 4):

Это по каким же эврикам?

Ключ - корень в обоих случаях.
Фасмер даже допускает общность происхождения.

I род. п. -а́ I., сюда же заключи́ть, укр. ключ, ст.-слав. ключь, болг. клю́чът, сербохорв. кљу̑ч, род. п. кљу́ча " крюк, ключ", словен. kljúč, чеш. klíč, слвц. kl᾽úč, польск. klucz, в.-луж. kluč, н.-луж. kluc. Родственно балт. словам, приведенным на клюка́, а также греч. κληΐς, дор. κλΒ̄ίς, κλάξ "ключ", κλείω "запираю", лат. clāvus " гвоздь", clāvis "ключ", claudō "запираю", ирл. cló, мн. clói " гвоздь"; см. Бернекер 1, 528 и сл.; Траутман ВSW 137 и сл.; Вальде–Гофм. 1, 229 и сл. Сюда же с и.-е. skl- относятся д.-в.-н. slioʒan "запирать", sluʒʒil "ключ", др.-сакс. slutil – то же. II род. п. -а́ II. "источник, родник", болг. ключ (водата ври с ключ) "о шуме воды", сербохорв. кљу̑ч, род. п. кљу́ча "клокотание, бурление воды", кљу̀чати " кипеть, бурлить, клохтать". Обычно сближается с клю́кать " шуметь" (см.); см. Бернекер 1, 529; Брюкнер 236, но имеет смысл поставить вопрос об одинаковом происхождении с ключ I. Ср. нем. выражение eine Quelle erschließen " открыть источник".

Comment: Нашел видео. Посмотрите, пожалуйста. 
http://video.yandex.by/#search?id=21758567-04-12&where=all&text=%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B

Answer (score 0):

Версия в этом видео интересная, но она не общепринятая, а авторская. Некая гипотеза, проверить которую сейчас уже практически нереально. Но она не лишена здравого смысла, хотя может оказаться и за уши притянутой. То есть у дверного ключа якобы корень "кл-" (от "кол" - кругляш - самый примитивный ключ, которым открывают щеколду в деревенских домах - изогнутая проволока. Суффикс - "-юч-", возникший от "-ук-" (было сначала "клюка", или "клюк", потом "ключ"). А в слове ключ как водный источник корень "-люч" (луч, излучать, вода излучается - то есть изливается, разбрызгивается, луч - струя воды). "К-" - приставка, которая раньше была предлогом.

Так что ответ на Ваш вопрос - потому что есть такая альтернативная точка зрения, как в этом видео.